# Как в linux определить процессы ядра и пользовательские процессы

Tags: linux, bash

Как в linux определить процессы ядра и пользовательские процессы.

Comment: Принятый вами ответ наверняка неверен. Пожалуйста, прочитайте второй ответ: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/528603/181472. Если он отвечает на ваш вопрос, то есть смысл переставить галочку.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В современном linux, в отличие от многих других Unix есть так называемые "процессы ядра". По суди это просто части самого ядра, функции общего кода ядра, работающие в том же адресном пространстве и с теми же привилегиями, что и остальной код ядра. Единственное их отличие от других частей ядра, для них создаются отдельные записи в таблице процессов. Процессами они сделаны для того, что бы их выполнение происходило независимо от остальных частей ядра, с более низким приоритетом. Их выполнение происходит под контролем планировщика, как и все остальные процессы в системе.

Процессы ядра linux запускаются самим ядром, при этом родительским процессом якобы их породившим, назначается процесс kthread, с PID=2. Таким образом процессами ядра надо считать сам процесс с PID=2, а так же процессы у которых PPID (т.е. pid родителя) равен 2.

```
sudo ps --ppid=2 --pid=2
```

Пользовательские процессы - все остальные:

```
sudo ps -N --ppid=2 --pid=2
```

Так же по умолчанию `pstree` без параметров показывает только дерево процессов порожденных init, т.е. пользовательских процессов. Процессы ядра покажет `sudo pstree 2`.

Comment: Я всегда думал, что таким родительским суперпроцессом является init (являлся, до прихода systemd)

Comment: @jumpjet67  init - обычный пользовательский процесс (за исключением того, что это единственный процесс запускаемый самим ядром), он стартует все пользовательские процессы в системе, по `ps --ppid=1` вы увидите все запущенные при инициализации системы демоны и обработчики терминалов, они в свою очередь запускают другие процессы. Во многих unix системах такой штуки как "процесс ядра" в принципе не было. В современном linux они работают независимо от init и запускаются kthread'ом. Нашел еще одно отличие: у процессов ядра /proc/pid/exe никуда не указывает, так как нет выполнимого файла на диске

Comment: Ок. Вы пишите "Все процессы ядра linux запускаются одним родительским процессом `kthread`", а в комменте "`init` - стартует все пользовательские процессы в системе". А как они связаны друг с другом? init запускает kthread или наоборот? Просто получилось много умных слов, мне как далёкому от этих дел пользователю мало что из них стало ясно.

Comment: @jumpjet67 Подумав, я дописал в ответе про pstree. По нему видно, что у linux два независимых дерева процессов, пользовательские - порожденные init, и ядерные - порожденные kthread. Да, я немного слукавил написав, что init единственный запускаемый ядром процесс. Это у других unix у которых нет ядерных процессов init - общий родитель всего. А в linux ядерные процессы есть, они даже работают в адресном пространстве ядра и ядро само стартует их по мере необходимости, назначая родителем pthread, независимо от init.